# C# WordprocessingDocument Parse Table As Is To Another .DOCX File

Tags: c#, copy-paste

I'm recently new at parsing the OpenXml format and curious if there is an easier approach to my problem.

The problem is illustrated in this image;

**Image:**

[image]

The furthest document on the left is **sample_tables.docx** and contains three random tables with various styles.  What I want to do is for each table instance in the file, I want to parse the contents and style as-is and create a brand new file (.docx) for each table instance.

I developed this sample C# code to automatically parse the contents of each table instance to create a separate .docx file that contains each table instance.  Each parse table instance is shown in the three images on the right of the image.

My question is this.  Since I basically reading openxml is there just a quick short-cut to copy all the relevant xml associated with the given table instance ( in **sample_tables.docx** ) to create a 1:1 ( colors, borders, shading, ... ) copy of it in another file?

Here is my C# code:

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;


namespace sample_table_parser
{
    class Program
    {

        //
        // given a Word table instance, it will capture the contents and create a 
        // new Word file ( .docx ) with that table
        //
        static private void parse_word_table( Table tbl, string file_name )
        {
            using ( WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create( file_name , WordprocessingDocumentType.Document ))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mdp = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                mdp.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mdp.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

                Table table = new Table();
                TableRow tableRow;
                TableCell tableCell;

                foreach ( TableRow row in tbl.Descendants<TableRow>() )
                {
                    tableRow = new TableRow();

                    foreach ( TableCell cell in row.Descendants<TableCell>() )
                    {
                        tableCell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(cell.InnerText))));
                        tableRow.Append(tableCell);
                    }

                    table.AppendChild(tableRow);
                }

                body.AppendChild(table);
                mdp.Document.Save();
            }
        }



        //
        // Main
        // 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string file_that_has_tables = "sample_tables.docx";

            WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file_that_has_tables, false);
            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            foreach (var b in body)
            {
                if (b.ToString() == "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table")
                {
                    counter++;
                    Table fooTable = (Table)b;
                    parse_word_table(fooTable, "table_" + counter + ".docx");
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked way too much, and its not clear exactly what you want.  You gave a whole lot of code but didn't say what if anything was wrong with it.  How can anyone answer if you haven't said what the exact problem is?

Comment: The problem with my code is that is just capture the table contents.  For each table instance, I want to see if there is a way to automatically record if the table has a border and if so, what is the style, if the table uses colors, what are the colors used, and on and on.  I know I can capture each style of a table with checks ( several if conditions ) but just curious if there is a short cut to capture all styles of a table in a step or two.  Is that more clear?